# Number of equivalence classes in $P$

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, polynomial-time

I am currently taking a course which involves computational complexity. I was told that polynomial equivalence (polynomial time reduction) divides P into exactly 3 equivalent classes, namely $\phi$ , $\Sigma^*$ and $P - \{\phi,\Sigma^*\}$. I am unable to figure out how this is true, specifically how if $L_1,L_2 \in P, L_1 \sim_P L_2$. I think there's a simple fact/idea I am missing out on, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $L_1 \in \mathsf{P}$ and $L_2$ is non-trivial. Pick $y \in L_2$ and $z \notin L_2$ arbitrary. The following is a polynomial time reduction from $L_1$ to $L_2$:

- Input: $x$.
- Check whether $x \in L_1$.
- If so, output $y$.
- Otherwise, output $z$.

This runs in polynomial time since $L_1 \in \mathsf{P}$.

Comment: AKA "solving the problem in the reduction"

Answer (score 2):

The existing answer is good, but doesn't tackle the empty and full languages and also leaves some doubts unspecified. I'll solve the full question.

---

First, let's be clear about our definitions: $L_1 \leq_p L_2$ when there is a *polynomial-time mapping reduction* from $L_1$ to $L_2$. That is, there is a function $f(x)$ from $L_1$ to $L_2$ so that

1. it is a mapping reduction, i.e. $x\in L_1 \Leftrightarrow f(x)\in L_2$, and
2. $f(x)$ is computable in $O(p(|x|))$, with $p$ some polynomial.

Polynomial equivalence $L_1 \sim_p L_2$ holds when $L_1 \leq_p L_2$ and $L_2\leq_p L_1$.

$P$ is the class of languages where each word $x$ can be decided to be in the language within $O(p(|x|))$, where $p$ is a polynomial once again.

---

Consider two languages $L_1$ and $L_2$ in $P\setminus\{\emptyset,\Sigma^*\}$. We have a budget of $O(p(|x|))$ time for an $f$ to map every word *in* $L_1$ to a word *in* $L_2$, and words *out of* $L_1$ to a word *out of* $L_2$. We perform the reduction as follows for a given $x$. (This is an extension of the existing answer.)

1. Decide whether $x\in L_1$. This takes a polynomial amount of time in $|x|$, so our budget is not exceeded.
2. Find a string $a\in L_2$ and a string $b\notin L_2$.

   - Wait, but how? What if it takes a long time to find those strings? Yes, that's possible. *But it doesn't exceed our budget!* Why? Because the time needed to search for a fitting $a$ and $b$ -- for example by randomly checking strings -- is *independent of $|x|$*. It is $O(1)$ from the perspective of the size of our input -- so are the checks by the way, since they are polynomial in $|a|$ and $|b|$ and independent of $|x|$ -- and hence this is also a polynomial-time step!
3. If $x\in L_1$ was true, set $f(x)=a$, else $f(x)=b$.

We never exceeded our polynomial budget, and we successfully found a mapping reduction, so $L_1 \leq_p L_2$. You can swap around $L_1$ and $L_2$ and hence find $L_1 \sim_p L_2$.

---

Why are $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$ different (both are decidable in $O(1)$ and hence they both live in $P$ too)? That's easy: if you use $\emptyset$ as $L_2$, then step 2 can't find an $a$. Thus, for all languages $L_1\in P\setminus\{\emptyset,\Sigma^*\}$, we have $L_1 \not\leq_p L_2$. But there is one $L_1$ language that can cope with the lack of $a$ in $L_2$: that's $\emptyset$ itself, because it never needs an $a$ since it rejects all strings! It's also clear that $\Sigma^*$ clearly cannot be reduced to $\emptyset$, because it accepts all strings and hence definitely needs an $a$ in $\emptyset$, so $\emptyset \not\sim_p \Sigma^*$. So, $\emptyset$ is an equivalence class by itself.

The same argument holds for $\Sigma^*$, but for finding a $b$ instead of an $a$. It is also an equivalence class by itself.

---

Conclusion: the equivalence relation $\sim_p$ partitions $P$ into exactly 3 equivalence classes: $\{\emptyset\}, \{\Sigma^*\}, P\setminus \{\emptyset,\Sigma^*\}$.